# Pi 3b (2015) model camera overlay png

Tags: raspberry-pi3

Slight problem with import picamera it gives me a copyright error and something about multiple names and such and with ./pngview it gives it a invalid code

Do i need to download the file from https://github.com/waveform80/picamera in order for it to work?

Also on another note is python 3 able to program the png overlay?!

heres my errors after a few edits:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ScriptTest.py", line 24, in <module>
    o = camera.add_overlay(pad.tobytes(), size=img.size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 891, in add_overlay
    self._check_camera_open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 540, in _check_camera_open
    raise PiCameraClosed("Camera is closed")
picamera.exc.PiCameraClosed: Camera is closed`

and this is the code i typed in from the pi camera information on github:

````
from PIL import Image
from time import sleep

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:

    camera.start_preview()

# Load the arbitrarily sized image
img = Image.open('/home/pi/Pictures/Overlay.png')
# Create an image padded to the required size with
# mode 'RGBA'
pad = Image.new('RGBA', (
    ((img.size[0] + 31) // 32) * 32,
    ((img.size[1] + 15) // 16) * 16,
    ))
# Paste the original image into the padded one
pad.paste(img, (0, 0), img)

# Add the overlay with the padded image as the source,
# but the original image's dimensions
o = camera.add_overlay(pad.tobytes(), size=img.size)
# By default, the overlay is in layer 0, beneath the
# preview (which defaults to layer 2). Here we make
# the new overlay semi-transparent, then move it above
# the preview
o.alpha = 255
o.layer = 3

self._check_camera_open()

# Wait indefinitely until the user terminates the script
while True:
    sleep(1)```
````

Comment: It sais the camera is closed but i cant find an option to change it

Comment: Please *please* do not post screenshots of code. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) meta post for why not.

Comment: try camera.close() it should close everything using the camera.... Typically i use this import statement  from picamera import PiCamera

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ScriptTest.py", line 1, in <module>
    camera.close()
NameError: name 'camera' is not defined`

Comment: Thats mainly what i get wherever i put it

Comment: The import camera works fine its just when i get to the lower levels of the code it starts messing up